# How do I set a custom keyboard shortcut to open the Start menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu

I use both Windows and macOS, probably macOS more frequently.  When using my Windows laptop muscle-memory has me hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up Searchlight to launch programs. In Windows you can get the same functionality by hitting the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and getting the Start menu, but I keep going for the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> keypress.

Is there a way to also set <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to open the Start menu so I don't have to worry about which keypress I do?

I have seen other Windows apps (e.g. Executor) use the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> keystroke, but Start does what I need so don't want to install another app for this.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> on Windows by default opens a window management menu. I don't care about losing a keyboard shortcut to this.

Comment: ALT-Space has been used as a windows default keystroke since AT LEAST windows 3.0 to bring down the window menu.  Ctrl-ESC will do the same thing as the windows key.  I think you are not going to be able to achieve this without hacks.  You might have some luck with [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) but I would suggest that you get used to using each OS as they were meant to be used without adding "hacks".

Comment: Where is the fun in that? I've "got used" to using the OS as they are over many years and am ready to customize them to how _I_ work now, thank you very much. Like I pointed out, other apps "hijack" existing shortcuts, and I don't ever need the current alt+space shortcut. I've never used that menu since Windows 3.0. I'll check out autohotkey.

Comment: TOTALLY!  I get it. I have the same problem when I am using my macbook! A funny use for this key sequence?  "Back in the day" .. and even still *sometimes*.. if a window is off the screen where you cant get the top bar, If you can get focus to the window, you can use ALT-SPACE.. then the `Move` or `Size` menu options to get the window where you want it.  Good Luck!